# Copy files to a new folder based on file name, and then name the new folder based on the file name

Tags: python, file, directory, copy, move

I'm trying to use python to automate the very manual process of moving test result files to a newly created folder.

Simply put, each part we test spits out 5 files, 3x .txt files, 1x .PDF and 1x .ZMP file. We have a growing folder consisting of hundreds of these files.

All of these files end in a serial no which is TSS-XXXX-XXXX
eg:

- 2354-472_5000_POB_EXYZ_small_L48_2354-472-03-TSS-2209-0021_pwr.pdf
- 2354-472_5000_POB_EXYZ_small_L48_2354-472-03-TSS-2209-0021_chr.txt
- 2354-472_5000_POB_EXYZ_small_L48_2354-472-03-TSS-2209-0021_fet.txt
- 2354-472_5000_POB_EXYZ_small_L48_2354-472-03-TSS-2209-0021_hdr.txt
- 2354-472-03-TSS-2209-0021.zmp

My goal is to create a script that will search for the TSS-XXXX-XXXX no., and then move all those parts to a new folder which is created based on that TSS number.

So the file:
*2354-472_5000_POB_EXYZ_small_L48_2354-472-03-TSS-2209-0021_pwr.pdf*
would be copied/moved to a folder named *TSS-2209-0021*

I've only really dabbled with python a few times, and I'm not able to find any other threads with a solution this, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

I tried:

```
import os, shutil

    src = r"C:\XYZ L48"
    dest = r"C:\XYZ L48"
    
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for file in files:
        if not file.endswith('.'):
            Dir = file.split("TSS")[0]
            newDir = os.path.join(dest, Dir)
            if (not os.path.exists(newDir)):
                os.mkdir(newDir)
    
            shutil.move(os.path.join(dirpath, file), newDir)
```

But this didn't give the desired result, it moves files around but not by the TSS serial no.

Comment: Can you be more precise than "moves the files around"?

Comment: Yes sorry that was very vague terminology. I want the files to be moved into a folder that is created and named based on the TSS-XXXX-XXXX number.

Comment: And what is your current code doing instead (which is what I was actually asking about)?

Comment: It's basically sorting not by the TSS no., but by the first half. Its created a folder called: 2354-472_5000_POB_EXYZ_small_L48_2354-472-03-

Comment: hi @Gromr123 I've posted an answer, please check if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

This code will go through all the files in `SRC` and if the `file name` contains `TSS` it will extarct the `TSS-XXXX-XXXX` and then it will check if the `TSS-XXXX-XXXX` folder exist in the `DST` folder (if not it will create the folder) and then it will move the file from `SRC\` to `DST\TSS-XXXX-XXXX\`

---

skip file if already exists

```
import os
import shutil


SRC = r"The Source Path"
DST = r"The Destination Path"

# create DST path
if not os.path.isdir(DST):
    os.makedirs(DST, exist_ok=True)
# loop on all files and get the folder name that each file is supposed to move to
for file_name in os.listdir(SRC):
    # if it is one of the files we are looking for
    if "TSS" in file_name:
        # extract folder name
        folder_name = "TSS" + file_name.split("TSS")[-1][:10]
        # create folder if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.isdir(DST + "\\" + folder_name):
            os.mkdir(DST + "\\" + folder_name)
        # if file doesn't exist copy the file
        if not os.path.isfile(DST + "\\" + folder_name + "\\" + file_name):
            # copy the file with the metadata
            shutil.copy2(SRC + "\\" + file_name, DST + "\\" + folder_name + "\\")
```

---

overwrite file if already exists

```
import os
import shutil


SRC = r"The Source Path"
DST = r"The Destination Path"

# create DST path
if not os.path.isdir(DST):
    os.makedirs(DST, exist_ok=True)
# loop on all files and get the folder name that each file is supposed to move to
for file_name in os.listdir(SRC):
    # if it is one of the files we are looking for
    if "TSS" in file_name:
        # extract folder name
        folder_name = "TSS" + file_name.split("TSS")[-1][:10]
        # create folder if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.isdir(DST + "\\" + folder_name):
            os.mkdir(DST + "\\" + folder_name)
        # if file exists remove it
        if os.path.isfile(DST + "\\" + folder_name + "\\" + file_name):
            os.remove(DST + "\\" + folder_name + "\\" + file_name)
        # copy the file with the metadata
        shutil.copy2(SRC + "\\" + file_name, DST + "\\" + folder_name + "\\")
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked an absolute treat.

Comment: I've run into a small problem with it actually. it will work great the first time. When you run it again it errors due to the folder and files already existing. How do I tell it to ignore or overwrite if an instance of the file already exisits?       shutil.Error: Destination path 'C:\test\2354-472-03-TSS-2045-0001.zmp' already exists

Comment: wait you want to overwrite the file if it already exists or skip this file?

Comment: Ideally yes. The first instance it runs the folders are unpopulated so no issues. However the next time you run it finds duplicates and then doesn't run. It seems that shutil.move doesn't have an option for overwriting duplicates, so you have to use an if statement that deletes them before it shutil.move runs. A shutil.copy2 might work as whether I copy or move makes no difference to me really, but I'm not sure what I need to change to get shutil.copy2 to work,

Comment: you can check if the file already exist and if so remove it and only then use `shutil.copy2()`

Comment: @Gromr123 look in the answer, I added another code, the first code is to skip the files that already exist, the second code is to overwrite files that already exist